# Primeng p-table not supporting row editing?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable, primeng-treetable

I am using Angular 7, and primeng 7.0.0 verstion p-table

Now I have requirment of row edit.I followed orginal documentation [primeng p-table row edit](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/edit)  But I am getting error while implementation.

Please help me,, I tried alot not finding any proper solution

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Did you import it's module to your app ?

Comment: Yes ,, I imported TableModule ,P-table other feauters working,,, Row editing not working

Comment: can you share some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using version primeng 7.0.0, updating to pre-released version (7.1.0-rc.1) will [fix this](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=58337).

Comment: yes it's working  but all rows went to editable condition.? why